# Creating a GraphQL field without a resolver

Tags: elixir, graphql, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I'm using Elixir with Phoenix and Absinthe to set up a GraphQL backend.

Ideally, I'd like to have a structure that looks like this:

```
{
  posts {
    published {
      title
    }
    draft {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

To do so, I thought I would need to delegate the `posts` field in my schema to an object that responded to `published` and `draft`.  I did this like so:

```
# In my Schema
field :posts, type: :posts_by_state

# In my Post type definitions
object :post do
  # ...
end

object :posts_by_state do
  field :published, list_of(:post) do
    resolve fn _, _, _ -> ... end
  end

  field :draft, list_of(:post) do
    resolve fn _, _, _ -> ... end
  end
end
```

This didn't work and instead returns `null` for the entire `posts` field.  However, if I changed the `posts` field in the schema to include a "blank" resolver, it worked as expected:

```
field :posts, type: :posts_by_state do
  resolve fn _, _, _ -> {:ok, []} end
end
```

Is this best practice or is there a better way to tell a field to delegate entirely to an object?  More generally, is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided by benwilson512 on the Elixir forums. Posting here to share the answer

---

The behavior you’re seeing here is expected, although usually the dummy resolver you’d use is:

```
field :posts, type: :posts_by_state do
  resolve fn _, _, _ -> {:ok, %{}} end
end
```

If you don’t specify a resolver, Absinthe will use the default resolver, which does a `Map.get(parent_value, field_name)`. In your case if the root value is `%{}` (which it is by default) then if you don’t specify a posts field resolver Absinthe does `Map.get(%{}, :posts)` which of course returns `nil`. Since the field returns `nil`, no sub fields are executed.

Really though, these seem more like things that should be arguments IE:

```
{
  published: posts(status: PUBLISHED) { title }
  draft: posts(status: DRAFT) { title }
}
```